# Forcing names with comparison operators in R (dplyr, rlang, tidy)

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

What is the equivalent of `:=` which can be used in place of `==` and `<` etc when I have a forced expression name on the LHS?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

i <- 1

dat <- tibble(n = 1:5) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(!! paste0("x_", i) := rbinom(1, 1, .5),
           x_2 = 1)
dat %>%
    mutate(!! paste0("test_", i) := case_when(!! paste0("x_", i) < !! paste0("x_", 2) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))

dat %>%
    mutate(!! paste0("test_", i+1) := case_when(!! paste0("x_", i) == !! paste0("x_", 2) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))
```

There is no :==, :<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`).  Also, it is better to `ungroup` to remove the `rowwise` attribute before doing the comparison

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    ungroup %>%
    mutate(!! paste0("test_", i) := 
    case_when(!! rlang::sym(paste0("x_", i)) < 
              !! rlang::sym(paste0("x_", 2)) ~ 1,
             TRUE ~ 0))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#      n   x_1   x_2 test_1
#  <int> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1     1     1      0
#2     2     0     1      1
#3     3     0     1      1
#4     4     1     1      0
#5     5     0     1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of other options are :

1. `.data` :

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(!!paste0("test_", i) := 
           case_when(.data[[paste0("x_", i)]] < .data[[paste0("x_", 2)]] ~ 1,
                     TRUE ~ 0))

#      n   x_1   x_2 test_1
#  <int> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1     1     1      0
#2     2     0     1      1
#3     3     1     1      0
#4     4     1     1      0
#5     5     1     1      0
```

2. `get` :

```
dat %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(!!paste0("test_", i) := 
           case_when(get(paste0("x_", i)) < get(paste0("x_", 2)) ~ 1,
                     TRUE ~ 0))
```